# NormalizeRange and MedianWindow in Rviz?

Tags: rviz, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey Guys!

I found some nice data set in the internet, which was recorded using a thermal camera. Now usually thermal cameras produce 16bit images, but I am not sure if the dataset I am looking at is rescaled 8bit or raw 16bit. So in RVIZ I can subscribe to the image topic and see the image without doing anything and rostopic echo shows me values from 1-255. But I noticed that RVIZ shows me the options Normalize Range and MedianWindow or if Normalize Range is not activated I can choose min and max values for the display. Now I have never seen that option before. Why am I getting that option? Is it a hint that the data might not be 8bit?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/392260/normalizerange-and-medianwindow-in-rviz?/) by [oroshimaru](https://answers.ros.org/users/82135/oroshimaru/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-12-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I understand your question is about thermal images, but I will use some information of depth images to provide the explanation, so please bear with me.

There is a very good [tutorial](https://www.stereolabs.com/docs/ros/depth-sensing/) from StereoLabs that explains how depth information is visualized:

> If you use the Image plugin, since the
> depth data are published on topics of
> type sensor_msgs/Image it differs from
> a “normal” image in that the data is
> encoded in 32-bit (floating point) not
> 8-bit.
>
> The parameters are the same as for
> Image, with three additions:
>
> **Normalize range**: Since a floating
> point image is not directly rendered,
> it is converted to an 8-bit grayscale
> image. Enabling this field means the
> normalization range is automatically
> calculated
>
> **Min value**: If Normalize
> range is unchecked, you can manually
> set the minimum depth range in meters
>
> **Max value**: If Normalize range is
> unchecked, you can manually set the
> maximum depth range in meters Manually
> setting the normalization range is
> useful if you know the maximum value
> measured for the depth and you want to
> keep the image scale static

Further in REP 118:
https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0118.html

> **Depth images** are published as **sensor_msgs/Image** encoded as 32-bit float. Each pixel is a depth (along the camera Z axis) in meters.

Moreover:

> Alternatively, a device driver may publish depth images encoded as 16-bit unsigned integer, where each pixel is depth in millimeters. This differs from the standard units recommended in REP 103.

I believe the same is happening with your thermal images as they also subscribing to **Image plugin**, take a look at this example of thermal sensor: http://wiki.ros.org/optris_drivers

```
thermal_image_view (sensor_msgs/Image)
color encoded image to be displayed with e.g. image_view
visible_image_view (sensor_msgs/Image)
RGB image from visible channel (bi-spectral technology necessary, only PI200/PI230)
```

And corresponding parameters:

```
palette (int, default: 6)
coloring palette in the range of 1..12
paletteScaling (int, default: 2)
scaling method for color conversion (determination of temperature bounds for high contrast coloring, 1=manual, 2=min/max, 3=1sigma, 4=3sigma)
temperatureMin (int, default: 20)
minimum value of temperature range (if manual scaling method chosen)
temperatureMax (int, default: 40)
maximum value of temperature range (if manual scaling method chosen)
```

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2021-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0